# Positioning of Inductor and Capacitor for Mains Voltage Noise Filtering

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, mains, filtering, mains-supply

In the [datasheet](https://gaptec-electronic.com/datenblaetter/5ACFEW_3.pdf) of this power supply, it is recommended to place the capacitor before the inductor for the mains voltage filtering circuitry, as it is shown on this image featured on the datasheet:

[image: Recommended Circuit]

However, in my view, it would make more sense to place the inductor before the capacitor. Let me explain. As of my knowledge, the inductor filters out the high frequency noise by not allowing it to pass through, whereas the capacitor filters out the high frequency noise by shorting it, which is less efficient as the strength of the noise grows. Therefore, I think it would be better to first "not let the noise in" with the inductor and only then short out the "noise that got in".

So my question is: Should the inductor be placed before or after the Capacitor for filtering mains voltage noise? And why.

I'm asking this because I've searched online and I've seen a lot of designs just like the recommended circuit on the power supply's datasheet but not the circuit I think is better.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

> *Am I missing something?*

Yes, you are misinterpreting the schematic and the meaning of the three components I mention below in the bullet points: -

- R1 and CX are for the suppression of incoming surges from the AC mains (immunity)
- LDM and CX are for reduction of unwanted signals generated within the converter getting back onto the mains (emission reduction)

> *Should the inductor be placed before or after the Capacitor for
> filtering mains voltage noise?*

The above tells me you are missing the point of what the schematic is trying to convey. Yes, we often use inductors on the mains side of the capacitor but, for the image in your question, that is not the information  it is trying to convey.

Comment: Like @tobalt pointed out, I was applying the right logic with the wrong premisse. I thought we wanted to filter the high frequency noise from mains and prevent it from entering the SMPS circuit. But we actually want to filter the noise from the SMPS and prevent from going into the mains. Now I understand.

Comment: @Dinis if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: I have upvoted all the answers but I did not choose just one because all of the answers are good and I have a serious difficulty choosing the best one.

Comment: @Dinis then just pick this, as your comment under it explains that you consider all answers helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The origin of the noise is the PSU and the mains side is the "clean" area into which you don't want the noise to bleed.

So the datasheet already follows your logic and your recommendation.

Comment: Alright, now I understand it. I just thought the mains voltage was the noise supply and the SMPS was the area we wanted to keep free of noise.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration is to reduce emissions from the converter into the power line as shown in the [datasheet](https://gaptec-electronic.com/datenblaetter/5ACFEW_3.pdf) itself.

[image]

The series resistor (in conjunction with the capacitor provide reduction of unwanted signals from the line to the converter.

[image]